# AWS Encoder PHP CreateJob

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files to S3 and transcode them using elastic encoder

I have my buckets and pipes active and I can upload files to my input bucket

I keep getting errors on the createJob function

```
$result = $client->createJob(array(
'PipelineId' => 'pipe.1',
'Input' => array(
    'Key' => $counter[10],
    'FrameRate' => 'auto',
    'Resolution' => 'auto',
    'AspectRatio' => 'auto',
    'Interlaced' => 'auto',
    'Container' => 'auto',
),           
'Outputs' => array(
    array(
        'Key' => $counter[10].".out",
        'ThumbnailPattern' => $counter[10],
        'Rotate' => 'auto',
        'PresetId' => '1351620000001-000001',                      
        )
    // ... repeated
),        
));
```

I deleted most of the other parameters in this function as I don't need them.

Edit : 
exception 'Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Command was not found matching CreateJob' in phar:///home/prosoccerdata/apps/demo/assets/plugins/aws/aws.phar/Guzzle/Service/Client.php:87
Stack trace:

phar:///home/prosoccerdata/apps/demo/assets/plugins/aws/aws.phar/Guzzle/Service/Client.php(76): Guzzle\Service\Client->getCommand('CreateJob', Array)

phar:///home/prosoccerdata/apps/demo/assets/plugins/aws/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client
/AbstractClient.php(105): Guzzle\Service\Client->__call('CreateJob', Array)

/home/prosoccerdata/apps/demo/beeldbank/beheer/upload.php(179): Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient->__call('createJob', Array)

/home/prosoccerdata/apps/demo/beeldbank/beheer/upload.php(179): Aws\S3\S3Client->createJob(Array)
{main}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same newbie issue. You have to changing S3Client to ElasticTranscoderClient.

```
use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;
$client = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory(array());
$result = $client->CreateJob(array());
```

I hope it helps.